# iOS Swift access string in array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I set up an array like this:

```
let modelArray = [
    "Casual":   ["health": 17, "weapon": 8, "crafting": 15, "social": 30],
    "Soldier":  ["health": 25, "weapon": 32, "crafting": 8, "social": 5],
    "Doctor":   ["health": 35, "weapon": 5, "crafting": 15, "social": 15],
    "Dorothy":  ["health": 15, "weapon": 15, "crafting": 20, "social": 20],
    "Asian":    ["health": 13, "weapon": 5, "crafting": 7, "social": 45],
    "Police":   ["health": 23, "weapon": 22, "crafting": 5, "social": 20]
]
```

How do I access the **String** (for example "Casual") value when looping?

```
for (index, model) in character.modelArray.enumerate()
{
    print("\(index) carries: \(model[0]")
}
```

This gives me *Type '(String, Dictionary)' has no subscript members*

Comment: That's not an array; it's a dictionary.

Comment: `model` is of type `Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Int>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Josh points out, your `modelArray` object is a dictionary of dictionaries. (`let modelArray : [String: [String:Int]]` is the full type information).

The dictionary within can't be subscripted using an `Int`, only a `String`.

Here's a version of your code, which will get some the health stat of each character:

```
for statDictionary in characters.modelArray {
    let health = statDictionary["health"]
    print(health)
}
```

---

**further suggestion**

Storing data like this in a dictionary is fine for some purposes, but you may find a cleaner, safer API can be made by creating structs (or classes) for holding this state information.

```
struct CharacterStats {
     let health : Int
     let weaponNumber : Int
    // etc.
}
```

Then enumerating would be even simpler and require no loose string keys (which could be mistyped).

```
 for stat in characters {
     let health = stat.health
}
```

Comment: Your answer did help the OP. But your first sentence is not correct. His `modelArray` is a dictionary of dictionaries and not an array. That makes it's definition to look like this: `let modelArray : [String: [String:Int]]`.

Comment: Huh, I had it correct before, and for some reason I changed it to an incorrect definition today. Don't know what got into me. Thanks for catching my mistake, I reverted back to my original answer (which includes the accurate type information).

Answer (score 2):

Just my point of view.

### A dictionary of dictionaries is ugly

Create a model type

```
struct Model {
    let name: String
    let health: Int
    let weapon: Int
    let crafting: Int
    let social: Int
}
```

and then your array

```
let models = [
    Model(name: "Casual", health: 17, weapon: 8, crafting: 15, social: 30),
    Model(name: "Soldier", health: 25, weapon: 32, crafting: 8, social: 5),
    Model(name: "Doctor", health: 35, weapon: 5, crafting: 15, social: 15),
    Model(name: "Dorothy", health: 15, weapon: 15, crafting: 20, social: 20),
    Model(name: "Asian", health: 13, weapon: 5, crafting: 7, social: 45),
    Model(name: "Police", health: 23, weapon: 22, crafting: 5, social: 20),
]
```

### Looping

Now you can simply

```
for model in models {
    print(model.name)
}
```

### Update: Searching

```
if let doctor = models.filter({ $0.name == "Doctor" }).first {
    print(doctor.health)
}
```

Comment: I agree, it is indeed ugly. Will change it up like this instead. Thanks!